# Как найти есть ли значение в столбце pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame, пытаюсь проверить наличие в столбце значения - не получается.
Подскажите что я делаю не так?

```
data = [11, 2, 23, 45, 44, 4, 7, 12, 34, 21, 9]
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['range'])

print(45 in my_df['range'])
```

На выходе **False** - хотя должно быть **True**

Comment: `45 in my_df['range'].to_list()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таким способом вы проверяете наличие значения в **индексе**, а не в столбце:

```
In [195]: 1 in my_df["range"]
Out[195]: True
```

---

**Вариант 1:** [pd.Series.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
In [188]: my_df["range"].isin([45]).any()
Out[188]: True
```

**Вариант 2:** [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [192]: not my_df.query("range == 45").empty
Out[192]: True
```

**Вариант 3:**:

```
In [193]: 45 in my_df["range"].unique()
Out[193]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

ну и наверное самый очевидный способ:

```
(my_df['range']==45).any()  # True
```